# ionic 3 "TypeError: this is null"

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

i am trying to redirect when i am getting data from firebase.
if it is null or empty then no need to redirect.

I am trying by using `this.navCtrl.push(ProspectPage);` but don't know why it is not working
it returns an error

`TypeError: this is null`

Here is my code, please check it and let me know what i am doing wrong here.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ProspectPage } from '../prospect/prospect';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-credentials',
  templateUrl: 'credentials.html'
})
export class CredentialsPage {
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
}

register(params){
// this.navCtrl.push(ProspectPage); // if i wrote here then it works
  ref.orderByChild("ssn").equalTo(1234).on("value", function(snapshot) {
    if(snapshot.val())
    {
      this.navCtrl.push(ProspectPage);
    }
   });
  }
 }
```

see register() there is one comment. If i add `this.navCtrl.push(ProspectPage);` at the starting of the function
then it works. but it should work when i gat the data from firbase.

Here, is my html code.

```
<button id="credentials-button1" ion-button color="stable" block on-click="register()"> Lets go! </button>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to your question is [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

> An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax than a function
>   expression and does not bind its own this, arguments, super, or
>   new.target.

```
  register(params) {
    ref.orderByChild("ssn").equalTo(1234).on("value", (snapshot) => {
        if(snapshot.val()) {
            this.navCtrl.push(ProspectPage);
        }
    });
  }
```

Notice the `(snapshot) => {...}` instead of the `function(snapshot) {...}`

Comment: Glad to hear that it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
this.a = 100;

let arrowFunc = () => {this.a = 150};

function regularFunc() {
this.a = 200;
}

console.log(this.a)

arrowFunc()
console.log(this.a);

regularFunc()
console.log(this.a);

/*
Output

100
150
150
*/
```

Your corrected Code is:

```
register(params){
// this.navCtrl.push(ProspectPage); // if i wrote here then it works
//convert to arrow function
 ref.orderByChild("ssn").equalTo(1234).on("value", (snapshot)=> {   
 if(snapshot.val())
    {
    this.navCtrl.push(ProspectPage);
 }
 });
 }
```

Comment: Can you please add some explanation?